# How to automatically adjust button size based on maximum screensize

Tags: html

I am looking for some help for a pretty straightforward question:

I have an AddtoCart button on a product page with a pixel width of 475 px (see code below):

```
#AddToCart {

width: 475px;

}
```

This size is perfect in a desktop browser. However, when viewing it on a smartphone (Iphone) the button does not fit the screen (to wide). Is there a way to automatically shrink the width of the button to the maximum width of a display if the width of that display would be less than 475 px?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe CSS `max-width`? If you have `max-width: 475px` and the browser is smaller, it should "fallback" to `100%` and just use the full width of the screen. (probably tons of other options, keyword would be *responsive web design*)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a responsive design using [meta-queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp), I think it is the best solution for a multi-support display.

You can also use relative sizes :

```
width : 20%;
```

It will adjust relatively to the size of the container.

Comment: I'm glad i could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use vw (ex. 90vw will always be 90% of the viewport width) along with media queries to change the width at different breakpoints.

`@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { INSERT STYLE FOR 0-768px SCREENS}`

`@media screen and (min-width: 769px) { INSERT STYLE FOR 769px+ SCREENS}`

There is more on media queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp